# Text search by first order formula

Tags: optimization, search-algorithms

I am searching for substrings that satisfy a given first order formula in a moderately sized text. The formula is made out of usual $\wedge, \neg, \exists$ and predicates `Equals(x, "some string")`, `Before(x, y)` and similar, where variables are pairs indices denoting substrings.

If the text is $n$ symbols long and the formula contains $k$ quantifiers, then the brute search is $O(n^{2k+2})$. This is quite a bit of time. I ask, **is there a way to significantly improve on this?**

Many ranges are 'obviously' not worth iterating over, but I don't see a good way to sufficiently restrict the search space, without enumerating all the possible substrings.

Comment: Since you already have some knowledge of your topic, it might be useful to share some references or give more details.

Comment: What do you mean by "and similar"?  I suspect the exact list might matter.  For instance, do you have `Substring(x, y)` as a predicate?  `Equals(x, constant)` should be easy to handle.  What are the semantics of `Before(x, y)`?  Is it that `x` precedes `y` in lexicographic order, or that there exists a substring `x` of the big string that appears earlier in the big string than `y`?  If it's the latter, have you considered using linear programming (where the variables represent the indices into the big string where each substring occurs)?  Lastly, why is brute-force search $O(n^{2k+2})$?

Comment: @D.W., I didn't list all the predicates, because I don't want to tie myself to them too much. The complete  list would be made out of predicates that check the contents of substrings (`Equals`, `IsDigitsOnly`, etc) and their locations (start and end indices. These are `Before`, `Overlap`, `ImmediatelyBefore`, etc). Note that the latter group can mostly be represented in terms of `Before`, for example, $Substring~x~y = \forall z (Before~z~y \to Before~z~x) \wedge (Before~y~z \to Before~x~z)$.

Comment: @D.W., Brute search is $O(n^{2(k+1)})$ because there are $n^2$ substrings and at most $k+1$ variables, all possible values of which need to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

The formula's you propose are very reminiscent of the operations of monadic second order logic: position variables, existence letter on position, relative order of positions, boolean operators and position quantification. As you probably know the power of this scheme equals regular languages.

The transformation from MSO to FSA seems to be horrible (negation is complementation, and existential quantification is handled using nondeterminism, hence exponential blow-up for each combination of the two).

Nevertheless, that gives a very different complexity, linear in $n$, but multiplied by a tower of 2-powers of height $k$.

Comment: That doesn't look right. I don't see a way to find all symbols at even positions using my predicates, so my system should be simpler than MSO. This is actually a problem for me, as I'd like to be able to describe *every other occurrence of "Foo"*...

Comment: Ah, completely missed that. You are right: FO is stricly less powerful than MSO. In fact you cannot specify "even length" in FO. That seems to imply you cannot describe every other occurrence: if every other occurrence (of a symbol) should be followed by another symbol, then you avoid even/odd lenghts (depending on where you start testing).